# Display TableView from TextField and passing data

Tags: uitableview, textfield

I'm learning Xcode and programming for the IPad. I have a TableView and can display it using a button. I would rather display it when I click on a TextField. If I dismiss the first responder, the keyboard, how then do I display the tableView? I have not found a example that fits. Any direction would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just simple

just in UItextField delegate method create your tableview.But return No ,that will never show keyboard and write your tableview code there.

here your have to use user defined delegates.

```
 //firstViewController
    ***********************
    @interface ViewController ()<UITextFieldDelegate,send>
    {
        UITextField *textField;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        textField=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 160, 60)];

        textField.delegate=self;

        textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];

        [self.view addSubview:textField];
    }

    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{


        TableViewController *table=[[TableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
        table.delegate=self;
        [self presentViewController:table animated:YES completion:nil];

        return NO;
    }

    -(void)clickedValue:(NSString *)name
    {
        textField.text=name;
    }

    //secondcontroller
    *********************
    in.h


@protocol send <NSObject>
@required
-(void)clickedValue:(NSString *)name;

@end
@interface........
@property (nonatomic, retain) id<send> delegate;
.m
******
    @interface TableViewController ()
    {
        NSArray *arr;
    }

    @end

    @implementation TableViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        arr=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"murali",@"mohan",nil];
    }

    - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
    {
        [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    {

        return 1;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

        return arr.count;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        cell.textLabel.text=[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        return cell;
    }




    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {

        [self.delegate clickedValue:[arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];;

    }
```

Comment: I need to be more specific. I have a view controller with a text field.The second controller is a table view. When I click on the text field in the forest view controller I want the table view to appear. I then need to select from the table view and have that data sent to the text field. Of course the keyboard does not need to appear. I hope this helps define my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. I am missing something. I have an error at line  "table.delegate=self;" I get 'delegate' not found on object type 'TableViewController'